# Android RelativeLayout recursive references... except not really

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

... in that no recursive loop is created.
Is there a workaround (or lint option) that alows placing 2 views so that one's horizontal position/size is based on the second, and the other way around with the second's vertical size/position?
Or another technique that does not use nested layouts?
Example (irrelevant values removed):

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/view2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/view2" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/robot_dialog_arrow" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Both the height of view2, and next to one another.
Logical, but I can't avoid `No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_alignTop' with value '@id/view2')`.

Comment: why do you say there are recursive references when the error says no such thing?

Comment: The problem might be the order. try the other way around so the second view is declared first.

Comment: @tyczj view1 refers to view2, and vice versa. Same problem if order is reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
android:layout_alignTop="@id/view2"
```

to:

```
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view2"
```

and change:

```
android:id="@+id/view2"
```

to:

```
android:id="@id/view2"
```

The `+` goes on the first occurrence of the ID in the XML file. In your case, that is the `android:layout_alignTop` attribute.

Comment: Yeah, that works. Hadn't thought of declaring the ID outside the view itself.